# How to read a binary data file in reverse order in c++

Tags: c++

I am developing a banking system app in C++ for my school project. In the recent transactions section, I want to print the transaction details in the reverse chronological order. For this, I have to read the data file (which stores the details of transactions) in the reverse order and print the entries. For this I have developed the following code:

```cpp
    int i,pos;
    passbook entry;    //entry is an object of a class passbook
    file.open("Records", ios::binary | ios::in);
    file.seekg(-sizeof(entry),ios::end);
    pos=(unsigned)file.tellg();
    for(i=NULL;i<=pos/sizeof(entry);++i)
    {
        file.read((char *)&entry,sizeof(entry));
        entry.print();
        file.clear();
        file.seekg(-2*sizeof(entry),ios::cur);
    }
```

Here is the class passbook as used above.

```
class passbook
{
    date t;   //To store the date of transaction
    unsigned long transaction_id;     //To store transaction ID
    float deposit,withdrawal;    //To store transaction amount
    double acc_no;    //To store account no.
 public:
    void print() const;   //To print the details of transaction
};
```

But this is just printing the last record a number of times. Can someone please help in finding the problem?

Comment: `sizeof` operator gives a result that has an unsigned type.   `-sizeof(entry)` will therefore be calculated as a LARGE POSITIVE value (that's how unsigned arithmetic works).    Converting that large positive value to (`streamoff`) - the type expected by `file.seekg()` as its first argument - will not produce the value you have assumed it does.

Comment: Not related to the problem: Are you sure that you can directly read an object of the type `passbook` from a file? If that object contains at least one `virtual` method, I would expect that the data written by one version of your App cannot be written by later versions...

Comment: If this is really a banking application why aren't you using a database?

Comment: One word: `std <algorithm>`! For manipulating complicated data with complicated algorithm and not reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I am developing this app for my school project. So I am restricted to use C++98 standard and file databases.

Comment: `sqlite` and `mongodb` are file database and `<algorithm>` was already in C++98 for a large part.

Comment: @peter a quick test indicates this possibly isn't the case: https://godbolt.org/z/YV-LaS, `-sizeof(entry)` does indeed produce a large positive value but in most cases casting this to a signed value happens to produce the correct value.

Comment: please add a [mre], we can't debug your code for you if you don't give us a runnable piece of code

Comment: @AlanBirtles -  You're getting lucky - or unlucky, depending on how you look at it.   If `std::streamoff` is represented using a signed integral type of the same size as `std::size_t`, then converting a large value of a `size_t` MAY do as you've seen.    However, such a conversion of an unsigned value to a signed value actually has undefined behaviour if the value being converted is outside the range of values that the signed type can represent.

Comment: @Peter that's why I said "possibly" as in "this might by UB but it is possibly not the issue causing the OP's code to fail"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the statement `file.seekg(-sizeof(entry));` , use:

```
file.seekg(0,ios::end);
file.seekg(file.tellg()-sizeof(entry));
```

And in place of `file.seekg(-2*sizeof(entry),ios::cur);` , use:

```
file.seekg(file.tellg()-2*sizeof(entry));
```